# Whitelist in google reCAPTCHA v3

Tags: recaptcha-v3

Is there any way to whitelist ip's from google reCAPTCHA v3 that google didn't consider those ip's as bot.

is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way of doing this using Google API.

The sad truth is, as of know, Google ReCaptcha scores processing is considered neither reliable nor stable, nor even predictable by the community.
So it might show 0.9 score for repeating scam requests easily, while giving 0.3 to real users that are more likely to be blocked by your threshold.

You can look through related [ReCaptcha issues](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues) on GitHub page. For example try to read [this one](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/248).

Regards.